# Cutting down on mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with say 500,000 entries. When a new user opens their profile - I'm presented with 500 pieces of data, i need to check id tag and check if it is in the database. That's 1 query. If it's not then I need to add this to the database. That's 2nd query. Overall that adds up to 1000 queries for new users.

Is 1000 queries too many? Instead of using mysql should I create a cache folder and keep the information in text files with the id tag as the name of the file - would this  be quicker? Thanks

Comment: It's not very clear what problem you're actually trying to solve here. Chances are there's a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: I'm trying to think ahead, would 1000 queries be too many? I've never dealt with large mysql databases before.

Comment: 500 pieces of data is a lot of data to be presented with when a new user opens their profile.  If you then need to run 1000 queries to add someone to your database, that's an indication that something is not being done as well as it could be.  It could be your database design or it could be the approach you are taking when generating your queries.  Hard to say without more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to insert a record if the user record is not already present but, if it is, you don't really want to do anything. if this is case then you might find the `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` form of `INSERT` useful.

This command will insert data a record if a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` is not already present but update when one is encountered. Have a look at [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for the details.

I do have to agree that 500 items is a lot of data to retrieve when someone logs is. Alwya retrieve the minimal information you need to and ensure that the relevant fields are indexed for speed of search (e.g., login, email addresses etc)

Comment: Thanks, I will try out having 500 queries!